# in javascript dom, is there a mapping of tagName to HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

cannot find a mapping of element tagName to HTMLElement, for example:

```
'DIV': HTMLDivElement
'A': HTMLAnchorElement
```

there is not a 1:1 mapping, for example

```
'B': HTMLElement
'S': HTMLElement
```

would be nice if said reference contained *the* distinguishing characteristic between an **bold** and **strikeout** `HTMLElement`, but maybe I hope for too much.

this has to exist somewhere in webland...

Comment: I removed my answer, since apparently I didn't understand your question. At all. 

You want, given a `tagName`, to know what kind of DOM element it maps to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a list on MDN:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference#section_14

Looks like it maps the DOM objects to the corresponding HTML elements:

> HTMLElement, directly implemented by: <dd>, <dt>, <tt>, <i>, <b>, <u>, <s>, <strike>, <big>, <small>, <em>, <strong>, <dfn>, <code>, <samp>, <kbd>, <var>, <cite>, <acronym>, <abbr>, <sub>, <sup>, <bdo>, <center>, <address>, <noframes>, <wbr>, <noscript>, <noembed>, <header>, <footer>, <article>, <aside>, <section>, <nav>, <figure>, <figcaption>, <mark>, <ruby>, <rt>, <rp>
>   HTMLAnchorElement, implemented by: <a>
>   HTMLAppletElement, implemented by: <applet>
>   ...

Comment: had no idea that HTMLElement was implemented by so many things.  surprised, for example, to see `dd` and `dl` but not `li`

Answer (score 2):

you can visit [here](http://help.dottoro.com/lagstsiq.php/#HTMLSpanElement),see the interfaces in javascript.i hope this can help you.

Comment: this is wonderful resource, now bookmarked - do you know if it's updated frequently?

Comment: seems some innacuracies.  for example, for <b> using `HTMLSpanElement`, whereas Firefox and Chrome use `HTMLElement`.  is this ie centric or mistake?  trust mdn _much_ more, despite sexiness of this site

Comment: @saimon xu - understand.  my point is that it appears to be wrong.  <b> and <code> generate a `HTMLElement` - according to Dottoro they generate a `HTMLSpanElement`.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the docs http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58190037
You'll see that elements are named like you wish (HTMLInputElement,HTMLQuoteElement, etc..)

But it looks like javascript is making no difference, you can always differ on `node.nodeName` or `node.tagName`